# Assunto do email de registro troca acentos por "entidades" html

Tags: bug, status-aceito

Só um pequeno erro, nada prejudicial.

[image: assunto de email/subject from email]

Comment: Btw, não achei o "Reportar um Bug" no site, então criei o tópico mesmo.

Comment: Todo site da rede Stack Exchange possui um prefixo/subdominio que começa com `meta.` e se olhar no rodapé do site verá vários links uteis. Fora que se clicar no menu principal logo abaixo aparece de **Stack Overflow em portugues** aparece **Stack Overflow em portugues Meta** https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0bZt.png

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ele não tem acesso ao meta com 1 de reputação. Ou tem?

Comment: @jbueno verdade, não estou certo, mas ainda sim tem o form de contato vou depois ver como orientar pessoas novas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Para participar do meta normalmente, são necessários 5 pontos de reputação.

Comment: @VictorStafusa obrigado, assim que possivel vou ver se consigo colocar uma orientação sobre o formulário de contato.